# how to list files in httpdocs?

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying get some files from website. And I want to do this but I don't know filename.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.examplewebsite.com/Directory1/Directory2/Text.txt");
HttpResponse response = null;
response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    long len = entity.getContentLength();
    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    // write the file to whether you want it.
}
String filePath = "Text.txt";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
int inByte;
while((inByte = inputStream.read()) != -1) fos.write(inByte);
inputStream.close();
fos.close();
```

how can be automatically this way? By the way I don't want to get in ftp server and list items and add www.exampleserver.com/Directory1/Directory2/  here.Maybe if i cant find another way, i ll use that but i dont want to write ftp 's username and password for the security.

Comment: You coyld try if directory listing on the webserver is enabled by removing the file name from your url. You can already test that with a browser.

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work.

Comment: you need to find the files name somehow, webserver security is preventing it from listing the files because people can use that to attack the server, most real websites have directory listings turned off.  can you have the person who runs it enter the ftp credentials, or store then encrypted somewhere?

Comment: Is sha2 encrypted ftp crediantals suitable?